# IBM Database for Redis + Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, ibm-cloud

IBM provides the 'Composer for Redis' as a Redis management service. for that, we can config the Redis connection as shown below.

```
  spring:
    redis:
      url: rediss://<user>:<password>@############.databases.appdomain.cloud:<port>
```

https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/access-ibm-cloud-redis-from-a-spring-boot-application/

Now IBM provides Database for Redis connection with base64 encoded certificate. Is there any way to connect this Redis connection with Spring boot?

I tried out the below-mentioned solution with ssl=false but it did not work as expected. Can we manage this without Jedis?

```
spring:
  redis:
    url: rediss://<user>:<password>@############.databases.appdomain.cloud:<port>
    ssl: false
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `ssl: false` should be `true` since IBM Cloud Databases for Redis is secure and uses a CA certificate. Then you'll have to configure your application to use the CA certificate that's provided with the database.

Comment: How can I configure the CA? Redis document does not contain about that. That's why I put SSL: false. That means we can avoid SSL validation. Can we do without Jedis

Comment: The IBM documentation about the certificate is here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/databases-for-redis/connecting-external.html#driver-tls-and-self-signed-certificate-support. I don't know if you can do without Jedis it's not my application.